# Flutter: List.generate isn't being populated

Tags: android, flutter, dart

First time using flutter: I'm trying to populate this column with a StatelessWidget but when I run the app, List is completely blank, even though List length is corretly displaying space for the amount of items I'm trying to display. When I debug the app there are no errors, so I can't understand if I'm submitting a completely blank widget or if I'm not inserting into the list the right way.
What I'm trying to achieve is displaying a placeholder card: once clicked it should follow the route and link to another page.

Here is my widget:

```
import 'package:progetto_esame_febbraio/utils/config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DoctorCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const DoctorCard({Key? key, required this.route}) : super(key: key);

  final String route;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Config().init(context);
  return Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 100),
    height: 150,
    child: GestureDetector(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: Config.widthSize * 0.33,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/facebook.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
           Flexible(
            child: Padding(
              padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
               child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text(
                      'Dr Richart',
                      style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      ),
                    const Text(
                      'Dental',
                      style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                      ),
                    const Spacer(),
                        Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                          Icons.star_border,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          size: 16,),
                          Spacer(
                          flex: 1,
                          ),
                          Text('4.5'),
                          Spacer(
                          flex: 1,
                          ),
                          Text('Reviews'),
                          Spacer(
                          flex: 1,
                          ),
                          Text('(20)'),
                          Spacer(
                          flex: 7,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
          onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(route);
        }, // rinvia al dettaglio dottore
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And Here is my home page:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 15,
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: List.generate(5, (index) {
                return const DoctorCard(
                  route: 'doc_details',
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having too much padding.

```dart
 return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),//here it was 100
      height: 150,
      child: GestureDetector(
```

Comment: Thank you very much! now it is working as intended